# How do I get Eclipse Galileo to stop restarting an external Tomcat run configuration?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I don't even have any servers setup except as an External Tool Configuration > Program. I'm using the JPDA connector, and yet when I do certain things like have Eclipse auto generate a serialVersionUID it automatically restarts Tomcat. I can't find where this might be configured in the project properties or the window preferences. I don't want Eclipse to do anything with Tomcat unless I'm starting or stopping. Thanks!

Comment: You added this tool config as a Builder for the project?  I'm not sure what advantage you might get this way, compared to using the support in the Eclipse Web Tools for servers.

Comment: EWT has always been inconsistent for me (especially the build process), and I almost always have problems with poor server management the longer a project goes. This setup except for this one issue has been rock solid, and I don't have to setup any dependencies since the build is done through Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, months after giving up, I was having a discussion with a co-worker about my Tomcat context, and finally realized what it was. I had reloadable = "true" in the context node, and it had nothing to do with Eclipse. In this scenario, all Eclipse does is communicate with Tomcat, and display console output. Tomcat was being notified in certain scenarios that files had changed, and it was restarting automatically. I set reloadable = "false", and this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does the server show up in the Servers view?

If so, double-click the server in that view, expand the "Publishing" area, and select the "Never publish automatically" radio option. Save the server, and (re)start it.

Comment: It doesn't -- that is just it, there are no servers configured under the servers view. I use an en External Tool Configuration > Program, which means all I'm doing is telling Tomcat to start and stop using the JPDA connector.

Comment: @hal1 - in that case, I can only suggest changing the setup to use a Server, rather than the way you have it now.